# Android Bottom navigation change text & icon tint on item selection

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I recently explored BottomNavigationView component of Android. I have 4 menu items and currently my BottomNavigationView configuration looks as below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/activity_product_details_bottom_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/menu_select_deselect"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/menu_select_deselect"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_product_details"/>
```

What I want is the distinguished colors for the element selected & the one's that are deselected. I also created Color state list file named menu_select_deselect.xml placed at res/color directory as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/tint_color_deselected"/>
</selector>
```

menu_product_details.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_product_details_home"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:title="@string/menu_product_details_home" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_product_details_product_documents"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_product_documents"
    android:title="@string/menu_product_details_product_documents" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_product_details_product_part_list"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_product_part_list"
    android:title="@string/menu_product_details_product_part_list" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_product_details_product_service"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_product_service"
    android:title="@string/menu_product_details_product_service" />
</menu>
```

Can anyone help me in what is wrong with the code, as only first element is displayed in white color even if I click on other 3 items?

Comment: Are all the items in menu_product_details.xml hold android:enabled="true"? In other words, are all the items enabled in the menu?

Comment: Yes all items have property set to true as android:enabled="true"

Answer (score 8):

You can change icon and text's tint color of select/deselect by adding

```
app:itemIconTint=""
app:itemTextColor=""
```

These are the 2 properties of BottomNavigationView and you can set it in your xml by adding drawable selectors in it.

But if you want to **change icon of selected item and not just color**, then I have different solution for you. Remove

```
app:itemIconTint=""
```

from your BottomNavigationView xml file and add below line to your class where BottomNavigationView is available:

```
bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

This will disable color tint effect of selected item icon and change the icon as per your selector drawable.

I had the same problem. I have added selector drawable for changing icon of BottomNavigationView item when its checked/selected. The selector drawable for each item is added in the menu file of BottomNavigationView as icon.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question, the mistake in my code was to replace the return value in onNavigationItemSelected() mentioned below, earlier I was returning false, whereas expected was to return true, it might be helpful for someone.

```
 bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case R.id.menu_product_details_home:
    break;
   case R.id.menu_product_details_product_documents:
    break;
   case R.id.menu_product_details_product_part_list:
    break;
   case R.id.menu_product_details_product_service:
    break;
  }
  return true;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your selector file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

and yes reference `@drawable` instead of `@color`

Comment: this is wrong, it should be state_checked not state_enabled

Comment: Yes, thanks @Deewankshi, it worked. FYI: I changed it to state_checked as pointed out by Kubicko

Answer (score -1):

While referring drawable use **@drawable** and not `@color`

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/activity_product_details_bottom_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/menu_select_deselect"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/menu_select_deselect"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_product_details"/>
```

Comment: both "@drawable" and "@color" are working fine for me.